# C++ function with a struct vector as a return value

Tags: c++, vector

I want to create a private  function in C++ (VS2010).
It should return a vector/array of structs/userdefined type.

However I think my declaration of the function in the cpp file is perhaps wrong. 
Or maybe already in the header. Can somebody have a look at it?

My header looks like this:

```
#pragma once
using namespace std;
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
class clsWString2
{
private:
struct udtWChar2
{
    wstring Text;
    int OrigPos;
};
bool m_bDirty;
vector<udtWChar2>pToWChar2(wstring u);

vector<udtWChar2>m;
public:
clsWString2(void);
~clsWString2(void);
void ReplaceCompareBinary(wstring uSearchFor, wstring uReplaceBy);
void ReplaceCompareText(wstring uSearchFor,wstring uReplaceBy);
void ReplaceByPos(int uStartPos1Based,int uLen0Based, wstring uReplaceBy);
void FeedString(wstring u);
void Append(wstring u);
wstring CharAtPos(int uIndex);
int OrigPos(int uIndex);
};
```

And my .cpp file looks like this:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "clsWString2.h"


clsWString2::clsWString2(void)
{
m.resize(0);
}
clsWString2::~clsWString2(void)
{
}
vector<udtWChar2> clsWString2::pToWChar2(wstring u)
{
vector<udtWChar2> n;
n.resize(0);

for (int i=0;i<u.size();i++)
{

    wstring sChar;
    sChar=u.substr(i,1);

    udtWChar2 nc;
    nc.Text =sChar;
    nc.OrigPos=i;

    n.push_back (nc);
}

return n;
}
```

Comment: The code seems fine. What problems do you have with it?

Comment: vector<udtWChar2> clsWString2::pToWChar2(wstring u) the compiler says "udtWChar2" is undefined.

Comment: could vector<clsWString2::udtWChar2> clsWString2::pToWChar2(wstring u) work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the source file, when you define the function, the return type is not in the scope of the class so the class in the vector needs to be fully qualified:

```
vector<clsWString2::udtWChar2> clsWString2::pToWChar2(wstring u)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I got it:

```
vector<clsWString2::udtWChar2> clsWString2::pToWChar2(wstring u)
```

Comment: But I don't understand why I need to say clsWString2:: Can't I make it so that it is obvious to the class that udtWChar2 is known to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use directly udtWChar2 as type , you need define type def or you need use as struct udtWChar2

Like :

in .h

```
vector  < struct udtWChar2 > pToWChar2(wstring u);
vector  < struct udtWChar2 > m;
```

in .cpp

```
vector < struct clsWString2::udtWChar2 > clsWString2::pToWChar2(wstring u)
```